# Register one type with multiple interfaces with one part of a collection causes Ambiguous Lifestyles error in Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector, diagnostics

so I have this class, implementing two interfaces:

```
interface IPerson { }
interface IMan { }
class Person : IPerson, IMan { }
```

and the following setup of the container

```
Container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AspNetRequestLifestyle();
```

And I want to register the `Person` class as follows:

```
container.Register<IPerson, Person>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

and then I want all the classes implementing the `IMan` interface to be registered as collection as follows:

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("My.Namespace"));
container.RegisterCollection(typeOf(IMan), assembly);
```

When calling `container.Verify()` this results in a `SimpleInjector.DiagnosticVerificationException`:

> -[Ambiguous Lifestyles] The registration for IMan (Transient) maps to the same implementation (Person) as the registration for IPerson
>   (ASP.NET Request) does, but the registration maps to a different
>   lifestyle. This will cause each registration to resolve to a different
>   instance.

How do I prevent this exception?

(we are currently using SimpleInjector v.3.3.2)

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade to Simple Injector v4 and add the following registration:

```
container.Register<Person>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

So in total, your configuration should be:

```
container.Register<Person>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<IPerson, Person>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

var assembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("My.Namespace"));
container.RegisterCollection(typeOf(IMan), assembly);
```

There are a few things at play here:

- Since v4.0, Simple Injector will automatically reuses `Registration` instances whenever it can. This means that although there is a registration for `IPerson` and for `Person` for that lifestyle, there will only be one instance of `Person` per `Scope`, since Simple Injector will reuse the same `SimpleInjector.Registration` instance that is in control over the creation of `Person` instances.
- `RegisterCollection` will try to reuse explicit registrations for types in its list and will reuse it, making it possible to override the default lifestyle that such a collection registration gets (which is `Transient`). In other words, a call to `RegisterCollection(typeof(IMan), new[] { typeof(Person) })` (which is what your call to `RegisterCollection` maps to), will try to look for an explicit registration of `Person`. Because of the extra `Register<Person>(Lifestyle.Scoped)` call, it will find that explicit registration, which allows the collection to return a scoped instance as well, which removes the error.

Comment: This results in the following verificationException:

-[Torn Lifestyle] The registration for IMan maps to the same implementation and lifestyle as the registration for Person does. They both map to Person (ASP.NET Request). This will cause each registration to resolve to a different instance: each registration will have its own instance during a single ASP.NET Request.

Comment: @Nemeas: This probably means you are still using Simple Injector v3. Please upgrade to v4.

Comment: Yes, turns out we are, and as I understand, this is not an issue in v4. An acceptable workaround until we can upgrade is to call container.Verify(VerificationOptions.VerifyOnly) instead of just container.Verify().

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows the minimal code to reproduce the issue. I tested the configuration I showed in my answer and it works, so there must be something more to it that you didn't show in your question.

Comment: Updated the question with the only thing relevant I could find, also added the version of the simpleInjector we use,.

Comment: Ow wait... you ARE actually using v3. I misread that. My advice: upgrade to v4.

Comment: With v4 I still had this error in an apparently normal scenario. Adding _the extra Register<Person>(Lifestyle.Scoped) call_ made the Exception disappear!